# How to fetch data from parse database in Cloud code

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud

Hello I am working on parse project in which I am looking how to fetch data from parse database in Cloud code.

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started

Here I didn't find a way to fetch data from any class. Is there any way to fetch data from class in cloud code ? If yes then how to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scroll a little further.  The sub-section called "Cloud Functions" provides an example function called "averageStarts" which does a find.

Comment: Cloud code uses the javascript interface so check those docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the Javascript documentation for parse. Here is a link to the relevant part to query in cloud code (javascript): `https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-basic`

From the documentation, to make a query to the GameScore class, this code could be used:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
     var object = results[i];
     alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
   }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```